# Having trouble with methods, string, char

Tags: java, string, char

I am currently trying to have my code return the letter 'd' in hello world and am not sure what is wrong with the code:

```
 public class StringTest{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String test= "Hello World";
        world(test);
    }

    public static String world(String original){
        int x= original.charAt(original.length()-1);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: change `String world` to `char world` and you can use just `return original.charAt(original.length()-1);`

Comment: Change the return type from String to char of method world.

Comment: Are you using an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse when writing your code ? 
You errors are a classical example of what a code linter would find and report via the IDE GUI......

Comment: You don't need a linter for this because this code won't even compile. The method is declared to return a `String`, so the compiler won't allow to return an `int` instead.

Comment: Hence the linter mate - the linter will pick up the mismatching return type by performing a static analysis of the written code. This is what makes IDEs great.

Comment: The compiler will already pick up the mismatching return type. IDEs compile _and_ lint your code on the fly and give you instant feedback, which is indeed great. In this case the origin of the feedback (the error) will be the compiler, not the linter.

Comment: Oh I see the problem now. Silly mistake. Thank you

Comment: Also I'm not sure what you want to do with the returned character, but you are not capturing it. You need something like char x = world(test); in your Main.

Comment: return original.charAt(original.length()-1).toString()

Answer (score 5):

In Java, `String.charAt(int index)` returns a character, and int can not be implicitly converted to char

What you can do is convert your returned character to charAt in String:

```
public class StringTest{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String test= "Hello World";
        world(test);
    }

    public static String world(String original)
    {
       return Character.toString(original.charAt(original.length()-1));
    }
```

> Also, an even easier way:
>
> Create empty String and conacatenate with your char.
>    Automatically this converts char into String since
>    we are adding an element to a String that in itself 
>    supports strings of these elements that are char:

```
    public static String world(String original)
    {
       return "" + original.charAt(original.length()-1); 
    }

}
```

Comment: At least mention @YCF_L who wrote part of what you are posting here as an answer in a comment.

Comment: @RannLifshitz Well, edit my post, I hope that now has no conflicts

Comment: Done, sorry for the inconvenience mate.

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán Not sure I understand what you mean when you say `and int can not be implicitly converted to char` Did you mean `and int/char can not be implicitly converted to String`?

Comment: @Bentaye int x= original.charAt(original.length()-1);

Comment: @Bentaye It is incredible that you have not seen the error in the OP question

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán as a matter of fact, you can write `char c = 1;`, it just won't be equal to `'1'`. I though your comment was about the return type, that is why I didn't get it. I get what you meant now

Comment: @Bentaye I know, you can convert int to char and vice versa, but the error lies in the way the OP applied it

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán It also lies in the return type of its method, there were 2 errors.

Comment: @Bentaye Exactly, the IDE tries to perform the conversion, but when an implicit conversion can not be made directly, the IDE simply shows an error

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán I agree with you, not trying to criticise, I just wanted to understand your sentence :)

Answer (score 3):

`String.charAt` returns a `char` ([see API here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-)), so you have 2 options:

Either you want to return a `char` and you need to change the return type of your method:

```
public static char world(String original){
    return original.charAt(original.length()-1);
}
```

or you want to return a `String` and you need to change your `char` to `String`, using `String.valueOf` for example ([see API here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char-))

```
public static String world(String original){
    return String.valueOf(original.charAt(original.length()-1));
}
```

Comment: Dude...... @YCF_L wrote most of that answer in a comment...... Don't you think he should get the credit for this ?

Comment: You did not write an answer, you wrote a comment. You do not get any reputation by writing comments. And you have credits, already 4 upvotes on your comment.

Comment: I wrote a remark about using IDEs, @YCF_L  wrote the answer in a comment.

Comment: @RannLifshitz Nobody said the opposite. He wrote a comment. If he wanted reputation he would have written an answer. He has 23K reputation, so I assume he knows that. No use to downvote perfectly good answers.

Comment: There is a basic concept in working relations / academia where when you use or base your work on someone else's work, you give them credit for it. That is the decent thing to do. Downvoting an answer when there is a comment detailing its content seems legit to me.
You want the downvote removed? Start your answer with giving credit.

Comment: @RannLifshitz Relax, this is trivial knowledge. Using a dictionary definition of a commonly understood concept without citing the dictionary is not considered plagiarism either. I'll upvote this answer because it's well written and provides links to the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused with what you are trying to do now.

The code in your post returns "d" as a String. 
Did you edit the post so it provides working version?
This is correct:

```
public static String world(String original){
    return Character.toString(original.charAt(original.length()-1)) ;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test= "Hello World";
    System.out.println(world(test));
}
```

Comment: yes somebody edited the question with the answer, I edited it back to its original form.